# Magnetic sensor NAS-DS01W0 (security concern about my network)

Tags: smart-home, security, home-security

I am writing because I am a little unsure about a device I have just purchased and installed in my home network. I have bought a magnetic sensor to detect if a door is opened and closed. The model is NAS-DS01W0 SHENZHEN NEO ELECTRONICS CO.,LTD. Sold by the company https://lloydscorp.com/en/

I am a bit concerned about the security of my network. And I ask the following questions:

Is this device secure?
Can I trust the providers?
Can someone remotely enter my network and hack my other devices (PC, laptops) through this sensor?

It turns out that to install the sensor device I used an application based on "Tuya" software. In order to install the device I had to give it the name and password of my network. The api that communicates with the app is also based on tuya. I know this information because I was capturing the requests that are made from the app.

Is there any way to check if this device is making strange requests or movements on my network?

I am a programmer (and a bit paranoid) but I don't have much knowledge about electronic devices and electronics in general.

Comment: may be more suitable for https://security.stackexchange.com/